# Why does this static field always get initialized over-eagerly?

Tags: c#, initialization, lazy-initialization, static-access

I am looking at [this excellent article from Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx).

While executing the demo code, Jon Skeet says that we can expect three different kinds of behaviours. To quote that article:

> The runtime could decide to run the type initializer on loading the
>   assembly to start with... Or perhaps it will run it when the static
>   method is first run... Or even wait until the field is first
>   accessed...

When I try this out (on framework 4), I always get the first result. That is, the static method is initialized before the assembly is loaded. I have tried running this multiple times and get the same result. (I tried both the debug and release versions)

Why is this so? Am I missing something?

Comment: the exact behavior is implementation defined as in you can't rely on it happening in a specific way but the overall behavior is definied (static fields load before their first access)

Comment: @ratchet, Hmm.. but is it always happening the first way. In about 10 tries... Hence I was confused.

Comment: I mean that if you tried a completely different compiler/runtime (which still conforms to the standard) you can get a different result, retrying with the same framework will just get the same result unless they added some non-deterministic behavior (unlikely)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When he says that "The results of running the above are quite varied.", he means that their **potential** results are varied.  The act of running the exact same combination of compiler and runtime will almost certainly produce the same results every time.  But other combinations (*e.g.*, the Mono Project's C# compiler and runtime) would be perfectly within their rights to do one of the other things.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ross. I was thinking that the same combination and different runs provide different results like the thread unsafe methods. To be sure I am clear, what Jon meant is that, since the specifications were ambigious, different compilers implement this differently. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.